# weight on Box using Pymunk

Tags: python, physics, segment, knife, pymunk

I have written the below program which is aimed at simulating a weight balancing experiment using knife edge. however, the weight of the box is not affecting the segment as shown when simulated. I am currently new on learning how to code with pymunk. kindly help me out on this

```
    import pyglet
    import pymunk
    import chipmunk
    from pymunk import Vec2d
    from pymunk.pyglet_util import DrawOptions

    window = pyglet.window.Window(800,600,"Knife Edge Mass Balancing Simulation",resizable=False)# W,H
    options=DrawOptions()

    space=pymunk.Space()
    space.gravity= 0,-100

    mass = 1
    radius=30


    ground_moment = pymunk.moment_for_segment(800,(0,0),(800,0),2)
    ground_body = pymunk.Body(body_type=pymunk.Body.STATIC)
    ground_shape = pymunk.Segment(ground_body,(0,0),(800,0),20)
    ground_body.position=0,100
    ground_body.elasticity=0.1
    ground_body.friction=0.1

    poly_shape=pymunk.Poly(None,((0,0),(100,0),(50,150)))
    poly_moment = pymunk.moment_for_poly(500,poly_shape.get_vertices())
    poly_body=pymunk.Body(body_type=pymunk.Body.STATIC)
    poly_shape.body=poly_body
    poly_body.position = 350,100
    poly_body.elasticity=0.1


    segment_moment = pymunk.moment_for_segment(mass,(0,0),(300,0),2)
    segment_body = pymunk.Body(mass,segment_moment)
    segment_shape = pymunk.Segment(segment_body,(0,0),(400,0),5)
    segment_body.position= 210,250
    segment_shape.elasticity = 0.1
    segment_shape.friction = 0.1

    size = 20
    box_mass = 0.0

    moment = pymunk.moment_for_box(box_mass, (size, size))
    box_body = pymunk.Body(box_mass, moment)
    box_body.position = Vec2d(300, 265.5)
    box_shape = pymunk.Poly.create_box(box_body, (size, size))
    box_shape.friction = 0.8
    box_shape.elasticity = 0.1


    space.add(ground_body, ground_shape,poly_body,poly_shape,segment_body, segment_shape, box_body, box_shape)


   @window.event
   def on_draw():
   window.clear()
   space.debug_draw(options)

   def update(dt):
   space.step(dt)

   if __name__=="__main__":
       pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update,1.0/60)
       pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the the segment shape has its weight in one end, and not in the center. This happens because weight in Pymunk is collected at the position of the Body of the shape(s).

Try to change the segment code to something like this:

```
segment_moment = pymunk.moment_for_segment(mass,(-150,0),(150,0),2)
segment_body = pymunk.Body(mass,segment_moment)
segment_shape = pymunk.Segment(segment_body,(-200,0),(200,0),5)
segment_body.position= 400,250
segment_shape.elasticity = 0.1
segment_shape.friction = 0.1
```

Comment: thank you, I am very grateful. I made the corrections and it worked. however, I do not know why the segment and Box are leaving the screen after falling.

Comment: Try setting the friction and elasticity on the shape instead of body for the ground :)